# I am writing query for database using SQL and during that i get the following error code......Duplicate value and error code is 1062. What should i do

Tags: database

My query is as follows

```
CREATE DATABASE CRICKET
SHOW DATABASES
USE CRICKET;
CREATE TABLE INDIAXI(
   MATCHES         INT                   NOT NULL,
   NAME            VARCHAR (20)          NOT NULL,
   AGE             INT                   NOT NULL,
   RUNS            INT                   NOT NULL,
   AVERAGE         DECIMAL               NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (NAME)
);


INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (155, 'TENDULKAR', 26,  9000, 45.6);

INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (160, 'VIRENDRA', 27, 18000, 46.6);

INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (165, 'UMESH', 28, 11000, 47.6);

INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (170, 'RAHUL', 29, 10500, 48.6);

INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (175, 'VVS', 30, 6000, 50.0);

INSERT INTO INDIAXI (MATCHES, NAME, AGE, RUNS, AVERAGE)
VALUES (180, 'KAIF', 31, 9000, 61.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NAME` field value yo are trying to insert is already there in the table. `PRIMARY KEY` implies value must be unique.

- either do not insert the same value twice
- or do not make NAME the primary key

Comment: Thanks for the help